# How to optimize with a function that decreases with time but increases with n?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

There are slices of cake where the consumer gets a utility value log(1 + j)beta^(t - 1) value from it where j is the number of slices consumed each day and t is the number of days since t = 1. What would be the OPT recurrence to maximize utility to determine how many slices of cake to eat each day for any certain beta?

Comment: for maximum utility maximization over the entire time period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we’re summing those logs, then letting OPT(n, t) be the
maximum utility of eating n slices in the first t days,

```
OPT(n, 0) = 0
OPT(n, d) = max from j = 0 to n of [OPT(n − j, d − 1) + log(1 + j) beta^(t − 1)]
```

Since utility decreases over time, optimal consumption over time does
not increase. Therefore an n-day horizon suffices. Compute OPT(n, n) and
follow the argmaxes backward.

Comment: is there only one argmax {OPT} because you assume cake is eaten every day?

Comment: @ArronStarmer There are no assumptions here. If you don't eat cake some day, and then eat cake on a subsequent day, then you can increase your utility by eating a slice on the former day instead of the latter.

Comment: So shouldn't the argmax be written as [OPT(slices - i, days - 1) + log(1 + j)beta^(t - 1), OPT(slices, days - 1)] on a possible day where no cake is eaten?

Comment: @ArronStarmer log(1 + 0) = log(1) = 0, so there's no need.